# Azure ML Studio: Create DATASET via REST API

Tags: azure, rest, dataset, azure-machine-learning-service

Please tell me how to create a Dataset via REST API.

There is a way to [create a Datastore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/datastores), but I can't find a Dataset.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to have a datastore to create a dataset.
- For example, use the common dataset `iris.csv` and point to it in the `path`.

```cs
DATA_VERSION=$RANDOM
curl --location --request PUT "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/$WORKSPACE/data/iris-data/versions/$DATA_VERSION?api-version=$API_VERSION" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data-raw "{
  \"properties\": {
    \"description\": \"Iris datset\",
    \"datasetType\": \"Simple\",
    \"path\": \"https://azuremlexamples.blob.core.windows.net/datasets/iris.csv\"
  }
}"
```

Please refer [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-with-rest#datastore) and [Create a dataset using the API](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/create-dataset-api#tabular) for more information.

Comment: Sorry for the long answer.
As I understand you, you suggest using the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/data-containers/create-or-update endpoint.
But on creation through it - I don't see these datasets in UI ML Studio